# MYSQL remote update is slow

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm looking for a way to update lots of rows in a DB(100K+). I'm connecting to the db remotely and updating the rows but it takes way to much time. If i download the db to my local machine and update them rows there its fast. I'm looking for a way to process the db on my computer then send only the changed part like all together. For example I can write a script which would download the db and edit it on my local machine then send it back and that takes way less time than doing the update. What I'm looking for is sending back only the column where the edit takes place and insert it into the server machine.

Update: Looks like its not the update script which is causing the bottlenect. Still need to find a way to figure it out whats causing the bottleneck

Comment: You need to find out what is the bottleneck here.  Typically sending an update script over to MySQL does not take that long, but rather the update itself is the bottleneck.

Comment: I will try to do the update on the server machine. The script which is doing it is a python script. The only reason I want to do it remotely is becase 1: My machine is faster and can do the calculation faster(not the db calc) 2: I don't need to change the script modules structure since thats annoying.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As you said its not the remote update query. I tried it on my server and while not as fast as local it still was able to run (on remote it hang and after 30min I closed it). Is there any command or any way for me to check what the script is actualy doing? I don't think I can use explain since the script runs multiple execute on a list.

Comment: You'll need to narrow this down. If you're running one or more queries per row then the round-trip time might add up and be a serious drag on performance. Can you run the script on the server? Are you comparing a server with a slow hard-disk to a local machine with a fast SSD?